# Extract a part of a string in python

Tags: python, string

I have a `.txt` file that has a really long `RNAm` sequence. I don´t know the exact length of the sequence.

What I need to do is extract the part of the sequence that is valid, meaning it starts with "`AUG`" and ends in "`UAA`" "`UAG`" or "`UGA`". Since the sequence is too long I don´t know the index of any of the letters or where the valid sequence is.

I need to save the new sequence in another variable.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What code have you tried? Give some examples of what's valid and what isn't, and also post the contents of your  `txt` file.

Comment: You should add a short excerpt of the txt-file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, what you need to do, without coding the whole thing for you, is:

**Example string:**

```
rnaSequence = 'ACGUAFBHUAUAUAGAAAAUGGAGAGAGAAAAUUUGGGGGGGAAAAAAUAAAAAGGGUAUAUAGAUGAGAGAGA'
```

You will want to find the index of the 'AUG' and the index of 'UAA', 'UAG', or 'UGA' .. Something like this

```
rnaStart = rnaSequence.index(begin)
```

Then you'll need to set the slice of the string to a new variable

```
rnaSubstring = rnaSequence[rnaStart:rnaEnd+3]
```

Which in my string above, returns:

```
AUGGAGAGAGAAAAUUUGGGGGGGAAAAAAUAA
```